# Is there a query to select random row from a set of returned rows from a SELECT statement in sql?

Tags: mysql, select, random

Suppose a SELECT query returns 10 rows. Is there any one line query such as this (which I tried but did not work) to select one random row from return results of a SELECT query -

```
select name from (select * from my_table where age > 10 ORDER BY age ASC AS rows)
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I think this should work.

Comment: Except you have a bunch of syntax errors. You're missing `FROM` in the subquery, and `AS rows` should be outside the parentheses.

Comment: does this work? `select name from my_table where age > 10
order by RAND() limit 1;`, i think you have a few syntax issues with select * *from* my_table and where age > 10 *AS rows* ?

Comment: ah rats, Barmar beat me

Answer (score 0):

<strike>One approach is to do LIMIT RAND() and enclose this in another SELECT statement which does LIMIT 1.</strike>

Another approach is to add a new column to the table, initialize it with RAND(), and then select from it, ordering by the random column with LIMIT 1.  You may even be able to do this on the fly, by JOINing your original table with another table consisting of a single column that takes values from RAND().

Comment: This won't work. The argument to `LIMIT` has to be a literal, not an expression.

Comment: @Barmar is this in the SQL standard, or is it just MySQL?  Anyhow, thanks, I will cross out that part.

Comment: I don't know if it's in the SQL standard, but it's definitely in MySQL.

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is correct, you just have the syntax wrong.

```
select name from (
  select * 
  FROM my_table 
  where age > 10) AS rows
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1;
```

You were missing `FROM` in the subquery, and the alias for the subquery goes outside the parentheses.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/77da1d/1)

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I had FROM in the query. But I saw your demo. Actually I guess I have to add AS ROWS part after braces. I would try it in my query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just one thing, in PSQL instead of RAND() function random() worked.

Comment: @Strawberry I'm guessing this is a simplification of the real query, where he needs a subquery.